# Issue with visibility of Transparent child form in Win 7 OS

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to have a Transparent form as child to another form.

For creating a Transparent form (say this form is: NewChild), I have set the "TransparencyKey" property and "BackColor" property to same color (say Red)

Note: My parent form BackColor do not have Red color.

Now in the Parent form on some button Click, I have code like this:

```
NewChild child = new NewChild();
int iErro = SetParent(child.Handle, (int)this.Handle); // Set parent to this child form
child.Location = new Point(300, 300);
child.Size = new Size(300, 130);
child.Show();
```

I can able to see the child transparent form inside parent form in Windows 8.0, 8.1, 10.0.

**BUT could not see the child form in WINDOWS 7.0.**

Please let me know if this is an issue with Win 7.0 OS or any thing I am missing

Comment: Issue? Hmm, interesting - you are hacking the infrastructure with that `SetParent` call and "surprisingly" have an issue.

Comment: Hacking? This is what MSDN says about SetParent: "An application can use the SetParent function to set the parent window of a pop-up, overlapped, or child window."

Comment: I meant the `Form` class - it's not supposed (or let say is not expecting) to be used that way.